# Firebase database query to fetch particular data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[My Database struckture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4KyP.png)

This is my database in Firebase and I'm developing an Android application. Now I want to retrieve all the data from "Generated" node where my current user's userid matches the "userId" in data.

I want to know the query in Firebase to fetch that particular data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Query [firebase query](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/11/firebase-now-with-more-querying.html)

Read the Firebase Realtime Database Documentation to get some idea [firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

To Get Current User Uid

```
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String current_uid = user.getUid(); // user.getUid() will return null if you are not log in
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Query query = db.child("Leads").child("Generated").orderByChild("userid").equalTo(current_uid);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                      // do something

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Or Try This One

```
db.child("Leads").child("Generated").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    SomeClass someClass = ds.getValue(SomeClass.class);
                    if(someClass.getUid().equals("uid")){
                        // i don't if it is the best practice or not but you can do with this as well
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: The code is only working when I take UserUID manually (copying from Firebase console and pasting in ".equalsTo". If I take current_uid in ".equalsTo" it is not giving any result.
I even checked current_uid Value. It's giving correct current user's UID.

Answer (score 0):

To access every item from that reference you will need something like this:

```
mDatabase.child("Leads").child("Generated").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                final List<String> lstItems= new ArrayList<String>();

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String name = (String) ds.getKey();
                        String values = (String) ds.getValue();
                        Log.e("Values",""+values );
                        lstItems.add(values );

                    }
```

PS: you can remove `.child(uid)` in your reference if you want to get all the children of Generated (it's going to be all the uids).

Comment: OPs question doesn't have a `child(uid)` layer in the JSON, so your listener won't have any results. With the current JSON model this requires a query, such as Salman500's answer uses.